# share git ssh credentials with devpod

Tags: vscode-devcontainer, devcontainer

I am using [devpod](https://devpod.sh/) to make environments reproducible. Nevertheless, when I try to commit code I am getting an error that git is not able to find my ssh keys, so I get a 403.

Is it possible to share my git ssh keys with the devcontainer?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible to achieve with the mount capability of the `devcontainer.json` configuration file:

```json
    {
        "name": "container name",
        ...
        "remoteUser": "root",  
        "mounts": [
            "source=${localEnv:HOME}/.ssh,target=/root/.ssh,type=bind,consistency=cached",
        ]
       ...
    }
```